# React Beginner Question: Textfield Losing Focus On Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, focus, material-ui

I wrote a component that is supposed to list out a bunch of checkboxes with corresponding textfields. When you click on the checkboxes, or type in the fields it's meant to update state.

The textbox is working ok, but when I type in the fields, it updates state ok, but I lose focus whenever I tap the keyboard.

I realized this is probably due to not having keys set, so I added keys to everything but it still is losing focus. At one point I tried adding in stopPropegation on my events because I thought maybe that was causing an issue?? I'm not sure.. still learning...didn't seem to work so I removed that part too.

Still can't seem to figure out what is causing it to lose focus... does anyone have any advice/solves for this issue?

I consolidated my code and cut out the unnecessary bits to make it easier to read. There are three relevant JS files.. please see below:

I'm still a beginner/learning so if you have useful advice related to any part of this code, feel free to offer. Thanks!

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Form from './Form'

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
      mediaDeliverables: [
        {label: 'badf', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'adfadf', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'adadf', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'addadf', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'adfdes', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'hghdgs', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'srtnf', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'xfthd', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'sbnhrr', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'sfghhh', checked: false, quantity:''},
        {label: 'sssddrr', checked: false, quantity:''}
      ]
  }
}

setMediaDeliverable = (value, index) => {
  let currentState = this.getStateCopy();
  currentState.mediaDeliverables[index] = value;
  this.setState(currentState);
} 

getStateCopy = () => Object.assign({}, this.state);

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <Form 
            key="mainForm"
            mediaDeliverablesOptions={this.state.mediaDeliverables}
            setMediaDeliverable={this.setMediaDeliverable}
          />  
    </div>
  );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Form.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import MediaDeliverablesCheckBox from './MediaDeliverablesCheckBox';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  root: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    maxWidth: 600,
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  extendedIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 370,
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: 19,
  },
  chips: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2,
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

function getStyles(name, accountName, theme) {
  // console.log('>> [form.js] (getStyles) ',accountName)
  return {
    fontWeight:
      accountName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}



export default function Form(props) {

  const mediaDeliverablesOptions = props.mediaDeliverablesOptions;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  const CheckboxGroup = ({ values, label, onChange }) => (
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup>
      {values.map((value, index) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={index}
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={value.checked}
              onChange={onChange(index)}
            />
          }
          label={value.label}
        />
      ))}
    </FormGroup>
  </FormControl>
);

  const MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList = ({values, label}) => (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup>
    {values.map((value, index) => (
        <MediaDeliverablesCheckBox
        key={index}
        mediaDeliverablesOptions={value}
        onMediaDeliverableChange={onMediaDeliverableChange(index)}
      />
      ))}
    </FormGroup>
  </FormControl>
    );



  const onCheckBoxChange = index => ({ target: { checked } }) => {
    const newValues = [...values];
    const value = values[index];
    newValues[index] = { ...value, checked };
    props.setDesignOrDigital(newValues);
  };

  const onMediaDeliverableChange = index => (deliverableData, e) => {
    props.setMediaDeliverable(deliverableData, index);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList
        label="Please Choose Deliverables:"
        values={mediaDeliverablesOptions}
        key="media-deliverable-checkbox-list"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

MediaDeliverablesCheckbox.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default function MediaDeliverablesCheckBox(props) {

  let deliverableData = Object.assign({}, props.mediaDeliverablesOptions);

  const onCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
     deliverableData.checked = e.target.checked;
     props.onMediaDeliverableChange(deliverableData, e);
  }

  const onQuantityChange = (e) => {
     deliverableData.quantity = e.target.value;
     props.onMediaDeliverableChange(deliverableData, e);
  }

  const CheckboxGroup = ({ value, label }) => (

  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              key={props.index}
              checked={value.checked}
              onChange={onCheckBoxChange}
            />
          }
          label={label}
        />
    </FormGroup>
  </FormControl>
  );

return(
    <div className="MediaDeliverablesCheckBox">
      <CheckboxGroup
            key={props.index}
            label={props.mediaDeliverablesOptions.label}
            value={props.mediaDeliverablesOptions}
          />
      <TextField
        key={'tf'+props.index}
        id={'quantity-'+props.index}
        label="Quantity"
        placeholder="How many do you need?"
        multiline
        variant="outlined"
        value={props.mediaDeliverablesOptions.quantity}
        onChange={onQuantityChange}
        fullWidth
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Updated Form.js based on recommended edits by Ryan C.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import MediaDeliverablesCheckBox from './MediaDeliverablesCheckBox';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  root: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    maxWidth: 600,
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  extendedIcon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 300,
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 370,
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: 19,
  },
  chips: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2,
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

function getStyles(name, accountName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      accountName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}


// Failed to compile
// ./src/Form.js
//   Line 86:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

//   84 | 
//   85 | const MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList = ({values, label, onMediaDeliverableChange}) => (
// > 86 |     {values.map((value, index) => (
//      |            ^
//   87 |         <MediaDeliverablesCheckBox
//   88 |         key={index}
//   89 |         index={index}
// This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

const MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList = ({values, label, onMediaDeliverableChange}) => (
    {values.map((value, index) => (
        <MediaDeliverablesCheckBox
        key={index}
        index={index}
        mediaDeliverablesOptions={value}
        onMediaDeliverableChange={onMediaDeliverableChange(index)}
      />
      ))}
);

export default function Form(props) {

  const mediaDeliverablesOptions = props.mediaDeliverablesOptions;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  const CheckboxGroup = ({ values, label, onChange }) => (
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormLabel component="legend">{label}</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup>
      {values.map((value, index) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={index}
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={value.checked}
              onChange={onChange(index)}
            />
          }
          label={value.label}
        />
      ))}
    </FormGroup>
  </FormControl>
);


  const onCheckBoxChange = index => ({ target: { checked } }) => {
    const newValues = [...values];
    const value = values[index];
    newValues[index] = { ...value, checked };
    props.setDesignOrDigital(newValues);
  };

  const onMediaDeliverableChange = index => (deliverableData, e) => {
    props.setMediaDeliverable(deliverableData, index);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList
        onMediaDeliverableChange={onMediaDeliverableChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two main issues:

1. How you are defining your different components (nesting component types)
2. Not passing the index prop through to components that are expecting it

You have the following structure (leaving out details that are not directly related to my point):

```
export default function Form(props) {

  const onMediaDeliverableChange = index => (deliverableData, e) => {
    props.setMediaDeliverable(deliverableData, index);
  }

  const MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList = ({values, label}) => (
    <FormGroup>
    {values.map((value, index) => (
        <MediaDeliverablesCheckBox key={index} onMediaDeliverableChange={onMediaDeliverableChange(index)}/>
      ))}
    </FormGroup>
    );

  return (
      <MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList/>
  );
}
```

The function `MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList` represents the component type used to render the `<MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList/>` element. Whenever `Form` is re-rendered due to props or state changing, React will re-render its children. If the component type of a particular child is the same (plus some other criteria such as `key` being the same if specified), then it will update the existing DOM node(s). If the component type of a particular child is **different**, then the corresponding DOM nodes will be **removed** and new ones added to the DOM.

By defining the `MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList` component type **within** the `Form` function, you are causing that component type to be different on every render. This will cause all of the DOM nodes to be replaced rather than just updated and this will cause the focus to go away when the DOM node that previously had focus gets removed. It will also cause performance to be considerably worse.

You can fix this by moving this component type outside of the `Form` function and then adding any additional props that are needed (e.g. `onMediaDeliverableChange`) to convey the context known inside of `Form`. You also need to pass index as a prop to `MediaDeliverablesCheckBox` since it is using it.

```
const MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList = ({values, label, onMediaDeliverableChange}) => (
    <FormGroup>
    {values.map((value, index) => (
        <MediaDeliverablesCheckBox key={index} index={index} onMediaDeliverableChange={onMediaDeliverableChange(index)}/>
      ))}
    </FormGroup>
);


export default function Form(props) {

  const onMediaDeliverableChange = index => (deliverableData, e) => {
    props.setMediaDeliverable(deliverableData, index);
  }


  return (
      <MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList onMediaDeliverableChange={onMediaDeliverableChange}/>
  );
}
```

You have this same issue with `CheckboxGroup` and possibly other components as well.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks so much for the explanation. Very helpful. I tried emulating your code structure. I moved MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList outside of the form function just like your example, but now it's pointing to the period in "values.map" and showing me the error: "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ',' ".. Is there a reason why React isn't reading this function properly? I'm not sure I understand why it's having trouble here.

Comment: I would need to see your exact code after the changes. I think my example had some slight syntax issues due to leaving out pieces such as FormGroup. If you add the new code into your question, I can help find the syntax issue.

Comment: I updated the original question with the new form.js and added the error I'm getting commented between the code. Let me know what you think...

Comment: You just need to add back in the FormControl, FormLabel, and FormGroup elements within MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList. I only removed them to eliminate clutter from my main point, but in the process I left it syntactically incorrect -- the `{values.map...}` portion needs to be inside a JSX element (e.g. `<FormGroup>`).

Comment: I got it working! I added those elements back in, but the only thing it was missing was the parameter "values", which was coming up undefined, so I added it to the MediaDeliverableCheckBoxList JSX component node properties and now it seems to be working properly. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 4):

This issue is solely because of your `key` in the `TextField`. You must ensure that the key remains the same on every update. Otherwise you would the face the current issue.

Comment: I see... I added a key for each textfield. Did I do it wrong? I've got "key={'tf'+props.index}" which should give each textfield a unique key, no?

Comment: Each form element is uniquely identified based on its form key. if you have different forms with textfields having same keys, but those form have different keys, they would be uniquely identified. there would be no issue

Comment: There is no issue in giving unique keys but those keys must not be changing with time. Once a field gets its key, it must retain that key throughout the lifecycle of that component

Comment: I don't believe my textfield keys are changing over time. I only have one form component with a unique key. Inside of that I only have one "MediaDeliverablesCheckboxList" which also has a unique key that does not change. When that component iterates through values using "map" it generates a unique key for each "MediaDeliverablesCheckBox" component (I don't believe this ever changes?). Each textfield is unique based on the index value of each MediaDeliverablesCheckBox. So unless those keys are somehow changing on render, it seems like they're unique and unchangeable. Maybe I don't understand..

Comment: Okay, do one thing! do you have `react developer tools` extension enabled in the browser?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: Okay then open your browser developer console, there will a react tab. Goto this react tab. There will be an aim icon resembling a sniper gun aim sign. Inspect your required textfield through that icon. Then type in your textfield. And keep noticing the key value in that field. Does it change on every focus loss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195943/discussion-between-cmaxster-and-mukarram-ishaq).