# TextField looses focus onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was using an older version of the library and had things working as expected. When I updated to the latest, I started to see issues with loosing focus when typing values into a `TextField`. However, I can't generate a way to replicate the issue because I have a validation script and layers of scope that I'm dealing with.

Key observations:

- The issues arise when I change the component from `Input` to `TextField` => instant malfunction with focus.
- This is only relevant for a "controlled" component with an `onChange` callback; `onBlur` is not a problem.

There are similar questions/answers on both stackOverflow and in the issues archive using `TextField` in various contexts.

From what I can gather, there are several troubleshooting options. Would it be possible to let me know if there are others?

1. must set the name prop (not so with `Input`)
2. turn off `autoFocus`?
3. use value instead of `defaultValue` (required for `onChange`)
4. set `inputRef={input => input && input.focus()}`?
5. use an `id` that does not change value between renders
6. use indirection by wrapping the `TextField`
7. avoid defining functions inside the definition of the component

Other: to help debug, track the value of the active element using `document.activeElement` in the devTools debugger.

I recognize that a lot of this should be well understood from a basic understanding of html forms. However, what makes it tricky is that we are dealing with an API (a wonderful API at that :), that abstracts much of what is going on under the hood, and thus the need for an API-specific "howto".

Thank you for letting me know ideas for how to troubleshoot this thoroughly annoying and debilitating misunderstanding in how I'm doing things.

Thank you in advance!

- E

Comment: The most common cause I see for this is that the state change is causing the TextField to be re-mounted -- not just re-rendered. The most common cause of the re-mounting is that the TextField is within a component that isn't defined at the top-level, so each re-render the parent component looks like a different component type to React and everything under it gets remounted. One example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873912/react-beginner-question-textfield-losing-focus-on-update/56874906#56874906

Comment: Any further tips would require seeing the code involved.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you.  This is the approach I'm looking for to figure it out.  I'll report back once I digest the information in the link provided.